# Site design updates are live!

Tags: discussion, design

Most of the changes won’t be visible (except for tweaks to the header that were made to condense the space to get the question list higher); these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We are moving the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We are updating the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We've fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.
- Visually it should "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

**But more importantly, it will give you access to [the new profile](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/)!**

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: The mobile version of the Profile does not show a bunch of stuff that is on the right of the desktop version. The one I noticed first was the consecutive days visited counter is missing. The mobile page also says *nil* if you don't supply a web page link. On it's own *nil* means ... nothing. Sorry to say I think this change is <strike>fixing</strike> breaking something that wasn't broken.

Comment: Even though it says its updated, I don't see the updates like i did on math.se.

Comment: @Batman the new profile is now on :)

Answer (score 1):

The tag stripes are all wrong...

[image: zoomed in view of tag]

As you can see if you zoom in on a tag, there's a pixel on top and bottom of the white stripe around each tag.

In my mind, the stripe was meant to subtly evoke the classic vintage bicycle branding of a colored area with stripes that wraps all the way around the bicycle tube, like this: [image: example of striped branding on fixed up vintage-style bike] or this:
[image: example of striped branding from 1958]

If the stripe is chopped off top and bottom, then it doesn't work as well to evoke that idea of that style of classic bicycle branding.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be enough left margin on badges in the new profile page:

[image]

[image]

It seems like there needs to be more left margin and less right margin for the badge to feel balanced.

Answer (score 0):

So. It has come to this.

Users have reported multiple issues with the new profile, but it has still been pushed upon us.

Hang your heads, Stack Exchange.

Edit: with more experience with the mobile version I have to say it doesn't work. Items that look like they would link (eg tags) don't do anything, and there appears to be no way of viewing recent score updates. So the recent score that is highlighted just keeps growing.

Stéphane - is there going to be any reply to these reports?

Comment: And, since the downvote, I would add that the only feedback was negative.

Comment: I don't quite mind it.